# Change default customModule in Xcode storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is it possible to change default customModule generated from Xcode, I'm using multiple targets (4 targets). When I create a xib file or storyboard file, it generates with my second target name by default. Can I change this default generated customModule name to my first target name ?